# Rendering PDF in browser - the PDF is showing up when running under "localhost", but NOT showing up when replacing "localhost" with my machine name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, render

I have an MVC app that displays a PDF from byte data being retrieved from the database, and the PDF renders just fine in my internet browser if my browser is pointed to "localhost".  But, if I change "localhost" with my actual machine name, the PDF doesn't render.  The app works exactly as I expect except for that.  I have my site hosted in my local IIS, by the way (obviously).

The funny thing is when the PDF doesn't render, I can right click on the area where the PDF should render in and choose "Save As" and save the PDF to my computer, open it up, and it opens just fine.

**Question**: Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem?  Is "localhost" the exact equivalent to my machine name in all regards when it comes to IIS hosting?

I'm not sure if this even matters, but here's my code:

**Controller Code**

```
public FileStreamResult PdfGenerator(string id)
{
    Stream fileStream = GeneratePdf(id);
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=form.pdf");
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
}

public Stream GeneratePdf(string id)
{
    // get and return the PDF byte data
    byte[] pdf = (from i in db.Pictures where i.GroupId == id && i.blah== "YES" select i.pdf).FirstOrDefault();
    Stream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdf);
    return pdfStream;
}

public ActionResult DisplayPdf(string id)
{
    Picture picture = (from i in db.Pictures where i.GroupId == id && i.blah== "YES" select i).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(picture);
}
```

**DisplayPdf View**

```
@model blah.Models.Picture

    <object 
        data="@Url.Action("PdfGenerator", "ImageViewer", new { id = Model.GroupId })"
        type="application/pdf" 
        width="640" 
        height="480">
        <param value="transparent" name="wmode"/>
    </object>
```

Comment: +1 just for the longest title I've ever seen! :)

Comment: @Liam I have a bunch of other questions posted that have long titles, feel free to upvote those too, :) lol

Comment: I'm not sure, I would assume that "localhost" is equivalent in all regards to my machine name when it comes to IIS.... I could be wrong though.

Comment: Nah, forget that, says it doesn't apply to `object`

Comment: what happens when you just browse to the url? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, everything about the app works perfectly except the DisplayPdf view that contains the `<object>` tag doesn't show the PDF.

Comment: Are you using the ASP.Net Development server or true IIS? What are the two urls in question?

Comment: I'm not specifying a port when using localhost.  http : //localhost/ and http : //machinename/

Comment: And IIS has a default web site listening on port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough, this is a browser compatibility issue.  That certainly doesn't explain why it worked under localhost versus my machine name, but what I did was add the following inside my `object` tag:

```
<embed src="@Url.Action("PdfGenerator", "ImageViewer", new { id = Model.GroupId })" type="application/pdf" height="1024" width="768" />
```

So, if the browser doesn't support `<object>`, then it will render the `<embed>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, try adding the following to your PdfGenerator function:

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

Are you rendering the PDF in an IFRAME?

Comment: No, I'm just rendering the PDF within an object tag.  Do I literally put "SAMEORIGIN" as you have it?